# Keycloak starts very slow when offline_user_session table has many records

Tags: performance, optimization, token, keycloak, startup

We have something around a million users in our app. We use Keycloak instance (https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/) with **standard** configuration. 
Also we use Offline tokens, to which this problem is connected somehow

The more **offline_user_session** table has records, the more time it takes to start the keycloak instance up.

if it has 0 records, a start takes something about 30 seconds.

When it has 800 000 sessions, it takes 8 minutes to start

And when it has around 1 000 000 session, it can start for 30 minutes or more

I tried to find anything on the internet and looked up in the official documentation, but still no results.

Comment: Might be a problem with the database. Once we had the problem that keycloak could not start because the logging table was so big that the space for the database was full. Which version of Keycloak are you using and what database is this?

Comment: Hi) we use the 6th version but I checked the last 8th version as well. Works the same. Our database is Postgres 10

Comment: Hmm.. sounds like a problem with the database keys - but that would be up to the keycloak guys to fix that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When analyzing a user_session offline table, there is a problem related to good practices in defining this table.

| **Field** | **Type** | **Null** | **Key** | **Default** | **Extra** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USER_SESSION_ID | varchar(36) | NO | PRI | NULL |  |
| USER_ID | varchar(255) | YES |  |  |  |
| REALM_ID | varchar(36) | NO |  |  |  |
| CREATED_ON | int(11) | NO | MUL |  |  |
| OFFLINE_FLAG | varchar(4) | NO | PRI |  |  |
| DATA | longtext | YES |  |  |  |
| LAST_SESSION_REFRESH | int(11) | NO |  | 0 |  |

In the database layer, we have a construction problem, when using two columns with “varchar” types composing a primary key. This situation is the only reason for the problem presented, which is only evident in scenarios with many records.

The solution to this problem will be to exchange the primary key for a large integer data type, and leave it as columns (USER_SESSION_ID, OFFLINE_FLAG) as a unique index. However, this goes to the configuration adjustments at the application layer, which should be seen with the solution provider.

| **Field** | **Type** | **Null** | **Key** | **Default** | **Extra** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID | BIGINT | NO | PRIL |  |  |
| USER_SESSION_ID | varchar(36) | NO | UNI | NULL |  |
| USER_ID | varchar(255) | YES |  |  |  |
| REALM_ID | varchar(36) | NO |  |  |  |
| CREATED_ON | int(11) | NO | MUL |  |  |
| OFFLINE_FLAG | varchar(4) | NO | UNI |  |  |
| DATA | longtext | YES |  |  |  |
| LAST_SESSION_REFRESH | int(11) | NO |  | 0 |  |